# /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 34: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, kernel, dpkg

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,876 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up memtest86+ (5.01-3.1ubuntu2.1) ...
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 34: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
dpkg: error processing package memtest86+ (--configure):
 installed memtest86+ package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Setting up grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu26.3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.config: 34: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic (5.4.0-45.49) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not installed.
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic (5.4.0-45.49) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-45-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 34: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 memtest86+
 grub-pc
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```bsh
$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" pci=nommconf pcie_aspm=off"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 4):

The quoting is wrong in this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" pci=nommconf pcie_aspm=off"
```

It should be:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nommconf pcie_aspm=off"
```